# Electron stuck at loading screen during Aurelia Navigation Setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, aurelia, jspm

**UPDATE 1:** I have a new problem now

While attempting to install, and setup **Aurelia Navigation with Typescript and Electron** following these direction: 
https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript

I got up to the part where I run electron with **electron .** and that's when electron opens up, but gets stuck on the loading screen.

Gulp watch and browsing the local site seem to work, but electron always gives me the loading screen.

[image: Aurelia app on Electron stuck on loading screen]

**How can I fix run electron without getting stuck on the loading screen?**

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what version of Electron this boilerplate installs from glancing at `package.json`. However, `require('app')` no longer works as of Electron v1.0, you need to use:

```
import { app } from 'electron' // TypeScript
const { app } = require('electron') // TypeScript/JavaScript
```

The same goes for all the other Electron built-ins, like `browser-window`. Also, capitalization of some functions has changed in Electron v1.0. The easiest way to fix all these issues is probably to update to the latest version of the Electron type definitions available on DefinitelyTyped, and then fix the compiler errors that will show up due to the API changes.

Comment: I finally got electron to launch, but now I have a new problem. Electron launches but gets stuck on the loading screen, I can't see the full app unless I go to gulp watch and browse to the local site. Please check the above updated question.